# Advantage of memoization in recursive solution to Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was reading an article on solving the problem of `Longest Common Subsequence` at [geekforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/12998), where there are two solutions, one recursive, and another through DP by a 2-D array. The DP solution does it in `O(NM)` time, while the recursive one does it in `O(2^N)` time.

The main problem with the recursive solution is the occurrence of overlapping of subsequences, as given there. however, if I store each pair in a hash, so that the next time that value is required by a recursion of the function, it can directly fetch the value from the hash instead of recursing further. So how much will this addition improve the efficiency? Will it come to `O(NM)`?

And secondly, how come the recursive solution yields `O(2^N)` time? How to find out the complexity of recursive functions like this one, or the one to find Fibonacci sequence, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using a hash will make it `O(NM)`. The process, in this case, is called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (yes, without the `r`). Just make sure you don't use an actual hashmap container as provided by your language of choice, make it a simple matrix: if the value for the current pair is `-1`, compute it recursively, otherwise assume it is already computed and return it.

As for your second question, you can either do it mathematically to get the best bound, or get "good enough" by drawing it on paper like your link does:

```
                f(n)
               /    \
         f(n-1)      f(n-2)
        /     \        
  f(n-2)       f(n-3)
          ...
```

This should be enough to inductively suggest that it will be `O(2^n)`: the tree has height `n`, and at each node, you have two recursive calls that will reduce the problem from size `n` to size `n - 1` (which will be `O(2^(n - 1)`). So the size `n` original problem will be `O(2^n)`.

Note that it is not incorrect to say that fibonacci is `O(2^n)`, but you can get a tighter bound with other mathematical methods.

Comment: That's interesting. Imagine I am using something like a dictionary in Python or hash in Perl. What advantage will using a 2-D array give me over either one?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - I don't know how a dictionary is implemented in those languages, but there are two ways: using a tree (Red-black or AVL usually), which will add a `log size` factor into your complexity, or using an actual hash function, which will be `O(1)` on average, but might be `O(n)` in the worst case, and it will have overhead too even on average. Either way, this will be slower than checking and writing to the entry of a matrix.

Comment: Right. That's cool. But regarding the improvement, can you prove that memoization will reduce the complexity to `O(NM)`?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - yes: each function call for an argument pair `(x, y)` will calculate the value only once, then save it. Subsequent calls for the same arguments will check if it is calculated (`O(1)` if using a matrix in your case), and if yes, return that value. You would need to access `DP_Array[x, y]` in your DP matrix in the iterative solution anyway, which would also be `O(1)`, so the two are equivalent complexity-wise.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also answer my 2nd question, how to, in general calculate the complexity of recursive functions? In this example, you just showed that they are equivalent, hence the same complexity. But for problems, where there is no such equivalence, how to find it on its own?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - in general, the answer is also very general: use math :P. Sometimes drawing the recursion tree like I did with fibonacci will make it obvious, other times it might not. A lot of times the master theorem(google it) will work. Other times it won't and you'll need other theorems. There's no way to give a general answer I'm afraid, it depends on the actual recursive function.